# Basic/Digest HTTP Authentication in a Pyramid app

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid

I have a very simple Pyramid app (my first one) and I'd like to 'lock' a couple of view callables with Basic/Digest HTTP Authentication (the generic login popup). This app will be administered by just **one** user. So I'd like a very basic security.

I've read theory about Pyramid's Authentication Policy, AuthKit, repoze.who, etc. But still can someone give me a simple example/idea of a **very very basic security** in a Pyramidd app,  just to lock several vew callables from the world?

**Note**: If somebody else is doing Basic Auth for a wsgi-app through Nginx and you used [Cookbook conf](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/deployment/nginx.html#step-1-configuring-nginx) to run your app with upstream, you may confront an issue when after successful authentication Nginx leads you to 404. All you have to do is point your restricted *location* to the same upstream:

```
location /restricted {
        proxy_pass              http://myapp-site;
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have say one "/admin" section with one administrator you can configure nginx as a [reverse proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) with [authentication](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAuthBasicModule).

I'm using this to "protect" public sections of demo sites before opening to the whole world.

The advantage is that you can use exactly the same method for serving Django or Pylons applications, and it's very simple yet robust.

Comment: Thank you! I used to do such thing with .htaccess when I was a php dev. And now with WSGI I just forgot that I still can do this server-wise (and yes I run my Pyramid app through Nginx).

Still, I must admit, I missed a nice [recipe from Pyramid Cookbook](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/authentication.html#basic-authentication-policy). I  have studied it, understood it and was ready to implement and then I saw your answer:)